# Why do we require Lie group morphisms to be injective in this result?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I have a proposition I would like to prove that says that if I have a Lie group morphism $f:H \mapsto G$ that is also an injective immersion, then $h \subset g$ is a Lie subalgebra. Now, there is a result stating that if I have a Lie group morphism $f$, then $f_{*}[v,w]= [f_{*}v,f_{*}v]$, so $f_{*} (h)$ is a Lie subalgebra. I also understand why you require the morphism to be an immersion, since this way $f_{*}= df_{e}:h \mapsto g$ would be injective, and the image of $h$ through $f_{*}$ on $g$ would be isomorphic to $h$. So I have $h \cong f_{*}(h) \subset g$. I wonder, though, why do you require $f$ to be injective?

We have defined Lie subgroups as images of injective immersion, because this way there is a powerful theorem that gives us a bijection between Lie subgroups and Lie subalgebras. I just don't get why you ask for injectivity.

Comment: You don't need to require that $f$ be injective, as you have noted in the question. This question seems to be more of "why did the author write this question this way?" then, so maybe you should ask the author directly if they are your professor, or provide a source if you are learning independently?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that if you add properness to the map you get an embedding

Comment: Now that I think about it, it’s more likely to be due to the fact that we have defined the leaves of a foliation as images of injective immersions. I think we use this fact in the proof of the Frobenius theorem.